# Need to open the specified browser whenever I am executing my program it is redirecting to Mozzila Firefox

Tags: java

I need to open the specified browser whenever I am executing my program it is redirecting to Mozzila Firefox. This browser will not able my link, Internet explorer is the perfect browser to access my links.

```
public class LogsANode {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();

        int i;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the num which you want download the logs");
        for (int x = 0; x <= 15; x++) {
            i = sc.nextInt();

            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    d.browse(new URI("link"));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    d.browse(new URI("link"));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In Windows start the Internet Explorer and set it as default browser (for opening HTML pages).

Comment: Great.. its working i have one more question if i want to open the no.of num links each time its opening new tab.. i want to open the all links in one browser

Comment: try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe google.com");` use brower exe location and link

Comment: Runtime.exec() is the best approach here

Answer (score 0):

Browse method of Desktop launches the default browser to display a URI. You could change your default browser.